# How to test a Campaign Setting's Content?

Tags: system-agnostic, campaign-development, world-building, playtesting

I'm working on a pretty expansive campaign setting of my own right now, and I'd like to test it. **The question is: How do I do it?**

## Notes & Details

- This setting is generic, intended to be adapted into any system. I'd like to write specific rules for each system (D&D, Fate Core, etc) once I've got the setting itself established. (A basic system adapter is included already in chapter 10, see below)
- I'd like to get feedback before I'm finished, but I don't have the whole thing written yet.
- I've got a public playtest version that I'm constantly updating, but haven't promoted yet.

### Structure & Progress

The project contains the usual types of chapters found in a D&D campaign setting book.

1. Using this book (written)
2. Folk & Races (written)
3. Professions (mostly written)
4. Life in the plane (some details)
5. Worlds in the plane (just a little of the overview)
6. Classes of Beings/bestiary
7. History (written)
8. Cosmology (Overview written, other planes left for later)
9. Game Mastering (some notes)
10. System Adapter (written)

## Things I want to know

How do I test for these things? When is it best to test for them?

- Is the Setting interesting?
- Is it achieving the "bullet points" I use to describe it?
- Do the chosen System Adapter rule systems work well with the content?
- Are there missing elements that might make it better?
- Are there things that I should get rid of?
- Sanity Check/Smoke Test
- Are the *included rules* adequate for at least a quick oneshot?

Comment: Are you looking for a best way?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I'm looking to generate a list. I don't know if there'll be a "best way" per se; I assume that some ways will be better at finding some sorts of flaws rather than others.

Comment: Lists are a tricky one for this site

Comment: As regards @Wibbs comment, see http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176/23970

Comment: Are you looking to publish commercially?  Sell it?  If you're looking to test something, what are you testing to determine?  Some choices might be is it playable?  Is it understandable?  Without answering in a comment, I'm struggling to understand why the answer isn't give it to some people to read and maybe try to play it.

Comment: The problem here is that without knowing what you want to test your setting for, there's no way for us to know which way of testing it would be best. And we have to be able to judge that, or our voting system doesn't work. Therefore: **What do you want this setting to achieve?** If you let us know, we may be able to tell you how to judge whether it achieves it.

Comment: I've spent some time reading articles on testing RPGs generally (or rather, mostly advice exclusively about testing rule-systems, rather than content) and I think that has helped me think through things more. The problem is that I don't know if even a properly formatted version of this question is right for stack exchange. The more I break up the question, the more it answers itself at this point. Should I update it anyway?

Comment: @Arcandio Without telling us how you're planning to change the question, we have no way of knowing whether the changes you have in mind are good. You're going to have to use your own judgement. That being said, if you do change the question you might receive useful feedback - but if you *don't* change the question, you'll get no feedback at all.

Comment: I edited the question with my specific goals with the testing, may or may not be more appropriate now.